# Do we not have control over questions that get migrated here?

Tags: discussion

This question is a *user-support* question, and clearly outside the scope of our FAQ:
[Cannot Upload Custom Header Image into Wordpress Dashboard](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/41629/cannot-upload-custom-header-image-into-wordpress-dashboard)

How do we stop these questions from being migrated here?

Should we make our FAQ more explicit, regarding user-support questions (and directing them appropriately)? Or do we just relent, and include user-support questions in our scope?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope, we don't. Just treat it as regular question (unless something way out of line happens like someone sending us zillion questions about unicorns).

I don't see how that question is "clearly" outside the scope, but I know we tend to differ on such. :)

**[update]**

[If incoming migrated question is closed (with some specifics) it is now bounced back.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/126982/163749)

Comment: I [posted the question on SO Meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121689/migrating-out-of-scope-questions-to-wpse), also. This one may potentially fall in a bit of a gray area, but it would be good to get some resolution on the underlying issue.

Comment: @Chip could you elaborate (preferably in chat) what gives you such a strong definition of "user support" and that it is so completely out of our scope?

Comment: Just FYI, I can't generally use chat during the day. But, regarding this comment you left on the SO question: *For the record I (WPSE mod and FAQ editor) think is is big stretch to formulate and drag "user support" out of scope as it is currently written. I hope to drag Chip into our chat when he has some free minutes and talk this out.* - I have to ask, given all of our many scope-related discussions: why hasn't the scope been better-clarified? Also, where do *you* see the "user support" line being drawn?

Comment: @Chip I commented on more fitting question of yours with the points I want you to elaborate on. You are not being meaningful about what do you mean by "user support" and you seem to draw conclusions from current state of FAQ (as written by me from discussion on meta) that I hadn't put in there. Let's deal with "user support" and do we want/need to adjust FAQ to formulate that, before we use FAQ to justify condemning it.

Comment: @Chip also there is very specific [question about FAQ content](http://meta.wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/41/what-should-our-faq-contain), that I don't mind being revisited and reviewed as necessary

Comment: yes definitely, we should revisit that question. I don't see any of the up-voted scope answers ever having been incorporated into the FAQ.

Comment: see this quote from your link (emphasis mine): "***If a migrated question is closed on the destination (migration target) site as** anything other than "exact duplicate" or **"belongs on another site"** (but not generic "off topic") it will result in the migration being rejected. If a migrated question is deleted, it will also be rejected.*" - why do **we** not have a **belongs on another site** option for close votes? Having such an option would solve a **lot** of problems for us.

Comment: @Chip but we do?.. As clarification in "is off topic" branch of close vote. Only from quick check in chat it seems that choice of specific site is limited to mods (which would trigger migration).

Answer (score 0):

*sigh*

[Wordpress Malware Problem help!](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/43208/wordpress-malware-problem-help)

Our FAQ clearly states:

> Note that we do not handle questions... that require professional hands-on involvement... **recovering from hacks** and server issues

Comment: I realize that I'm probably the only person looking at this question anymore, but for anyone else who might still be, take a look at the response I got in the linked question. Basically: *who cares if it's explicitly out of scope; that's what the Community Wiki is for!* Such a response is indicative of a **network problem**, that unfortunately impacts us.

Comment: Breathe. :) I've commented there and pinged webmasters mods that such are not in scope for us.

Answer (score 0):

And again:
[How can I improve site/page performance of WordPress websites?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/43977/how-can-i-improve-site-page-performance-of-wordpress-websites)

A question that is asking about server-level/browser caching, that got migrated to WPSE simply because the OP used "WordPress" in the question title.

**Seriously: please make this stop.**

Answer (score 0):

#### Awesome!

[Off-topic question gets migrated here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/7224/how-does-one-import-a-wordpress-com-blog-into-another-wordpress-com-blog) (*irony*: migrated *from* the site where it actually belongs, as per our FAQ). Question gets one close-vote as off-topic. Question gets answers, but none accepted. Question asker apparently doesn't follow question from other SE site to WPSE, so the question flounders. Today, question gets community-ized, thus contributing to our ever-growing pool of unanswered questions.

I know the horse has been converted to glue by now, but this is why I continue to beat on it.

Comment: That thing is over year old. Is it really worth a bother? :)

Comment: One-off? Certainly not. But when "one-off" turns into *dozens*? At some point, yes: it becomes a bother.

Comment: You should see the amount of question that don't get migrated here, makes you wonder why the main site has such an active wordpress tag. They get as many wordpress question as WPSE does.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wordpress

Answer (score -2):

And yet **another** question migrated here, simply because it's asked in the context of WordPress:
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/42620/reasons-why-i-cant-view-my-site-over-https-at-all

Why, why, why?!?